# Kafka - How to read more than 10 rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I made connector that read from database with jdbc, and consuming it from a Spark application. The app read the database data well, BUT it read only first 10 row and seems to ignore rest of them. How should I get rest, so I can compute with all data.

Here are my spark code:

```
val brokers = "http://127.0.0.1:9092"
val topics = List("postgres-accounts2")
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount")
//sparkConf.setMaster("spark://sda1:7077,sda2:7077")
sparkConf.setMaster("local[2]")
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") 
sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Record]))

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

 // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
//val topicsSet = topics.split(",")

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "schema.registry.url" -> "http://127.0.0.1:8081",
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "http://127.0.0.1:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
  "value.deserializer" -> "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer",
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Record](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, Record](topics, kafkaParams)
)

val data = messages.map(record => {
    println( record) // print only first 10
    // compute here?
    (record.key, record.value)
})

data.print()

// Start the computation
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue lies in that **Spark is lazy and will only read the data that is actually used**.

By default, `print` will show the first 10 elements in a stream. Since the code does not contain any other actions in addition to the two `print` there is no need to read more than 10 rows of data. Try using `count` or another action to confirm that it is working.